# SQL WHERE clause in VBA: Use array-variable

Tags: sql, arrays, vba

How I can insert an array (stored in a variable) into the WHERE clause of a SQL statement in VBA?

```
recordset1.Open "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [NettingSet] = '" & varRecord & "'"
```

Originial string is:

```
recordset1.Open "SELECT Class FROM [BCBS279_NetSet_Basics] WHERE [LoadingID] =" & LId & "And [NettingSet] = '" & varRecord & "'"
```

I get this error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Array:

```
Dim varRecord As Variant
varRecord = slide7_netset_info_ID.GetRows(10, , 0)
```

This array just contains strings:

```
 Example_1, Example_2, Example_3, ..., Example_10
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `IN` in SQL and then construct the `IN` list using "join" in VBA:

```
". . . WHERE [Name] IN ('" & Join(varRecord, "', '") & "')"
```

Comment: @tmenke . . . Does this refer to the construction of the string or to the SQL call itself?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your swift Response. If I try it like that: recordset2.Open "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Name] IN (' " & Join(varRecord, "', ' ") & ")' ". I get the error: Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5).

Comment: it refers to the SQL Call itself

Comment: @tmenke . . . Then you should edit the question and show what the string looks like after it is constructed.

Comment: that's the concrete SQL-Statement: `slide7_netset_basics.Open "SELECT Class FROM [NetSet_Basics] WHERE [LoadingID] =" & LId & "And [NettingSet] IN (' " & Join(varRecord, "', ' ") & ")' " `

Comment: You need a space before `AND` and close the space after `IN()`:  `IN ('" & Join(varRecord, "', ' ")`

Comment: @parfait: Thanks for the correction. Unfortunatly the error still exist.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff specified, check how string looks after construction. Please print out the SQL statement and check result in Excel's VBA IDE Immediate Window by running: `debug.Print  "SELECT Class FROM [NetSet_Basics] WHERE [LoadingID] =" & LId & " AND [NettingSet] IN ('" & Join(varRecord, "', '") & ")' "`

Comment: In fact, @GordonLinoff, I just caught the issue. The last single quote should be inside parenthesis.

Comment: I think it's working: Debug.Print: `SELECT Class FROM [NetSet_Basics] WHERE [LoadingID] =0 AND [NettingSet] IN ('Example6', 'Example6_21', 'Example6_9', 'Example1', 'Example6_12', 'Example6_18', 'Example6_3', 'Example4', 'Example6_1', 'Example6_10', 'Example6_16', 'Example6_13', 'Example3', 'Example6_4', 'Example6_6', 'Example6_15', 'Example6_17', 'Example6_11', 'Example2', 'Example6_2', 'Example6_20', 'Example6_8', 'Example6_5', 'Example6_14', 'Example6_19', 'Example6_7', 'Example5 ') `

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! In the end I also adopt the proposal to use a loop to save a one-dimensional Array within the varRecord-variable (instead of the multi-dimensional array from the getrows-method) with the reason that "Join" only works with one-dimensional arrays. Moreover I Dim varRecord As String instead of Variant.